# Generate laplacian matrix from non-square dataset

Tags: python

I have a dataset as the following where the first and second columns indicate nodes connection from to:

```
fromNode    toNode
0   1
0   2
0   31
0   73
1   3
1   56
2   10
...
```

I want to generate laplacian matrix from this dataset. I use the following code to do so but it complains as the dataset itself is not square matrix. Is there a function that accept this type of dataset and generates the matrix?

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
from scipy.sparse import csgraph
import csv

G = genfromtxt('./data.csv', delimiter='\t').astype(int)
dataset = csgraph.laplacian(G, normed=False)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to process your node/edge dataset into the required form - from the docs, [Graph Represntations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html#graph-representations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than find a function that will except your data, process your data into the correct format.

Fake data `f` simulates a file object.  Use `io.StringIO` for Python 3.6.

```
data = '''0   1
0   2
0   31
0   73
1   3
1   56
2   10'''
f = io.BytesIO(data)
```

Read each line of the data and process it into a list of edges with the form `(node1, node1)`.

```
edges = []
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    (node1, node2) = map(int, line.split())
    edges.append((node1,node2))
```

Find the highest node *number*, create a *square* numpy ndarray based on the highest node number.  You need to be aware of your node numbering - is it zero based?

```
N = max(x for edge in edges for x in edge)
G = np.zeros((N+1,N+1), dtype = np.int64)
```

Iterate over the edges and assign the edge weight to the Graph

```
for row, column in edges:
    G[row,column] = 1
```

---

Here is a solution making use of [numpy integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).

```
z = np.genfromtxt(f, dtype = np.int64)
n = z.max() + 1
g = np.zeros((n,n), dtype = np.int64)
rows, columns = z.T
g[rows, columns] = 1
```

---

Of course both of those assume all edge weights are equal.

---

See [Graph Representations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html#graph-representations) in the scipy docs.  I couldn't try this graph to see if it is valid, I'm getting an import error for `csgraph` - probably need to update.

Comment: Instead of `z.T[0]` you could use `z[:,0]`, but even better: you could unpack as `rows,columns = z.T` I think.

Comment: Ah yes, ... the ```rows, columns``` assignment was an afterthought, I originally had the ```z.T``` slices in the next line.  Funny how you miss things like that. thnx.